# SQL query syntax error in AWS lambda; the word "Dec" is not working but "Dev" works OK

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, lambda

I tried to use this SQL code in AWS lambda

```
sql = "SELECT Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec FROM table WHERE id = 1"
```

But got the message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax

So I changed "Dec" to "Dev", then it works:

```
sql = "SELECT Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dev FROM table WHERE id = 1"
```

So my question is how can `Dec` be used in AWS lambda?

Thanks

Comment: check for your real column name  ..   in your table

Comment: DEC is a reserved word in MySQL. Rename your column or put it into backticks to escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your column name is a keyword or Reserved Words in MySQL.
To consider your column name `Dec`. First MySQL needs to ignore it as a Reserved name.use backquote symbol before and after your column name `dec`

`sql = "SELECT Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,`Dec`FROM table WHERE id = 1`;

I also suggest you not to use keyword and Reserved Words, as your column names.